# What are generic product states and generic entangled states?

Tags: quantum-information

I just have a question on the terminology since I am a beginner and am not sure of it. If we have a $3$-qubit system

$$(a_1|0\rangle+a_2|1\rangle)\otimes(a_3|0\rangle+a_4|1\rangle)\otimes(a_5|0\rangle+a+6|1\rangle)$$

and then we multiply them together it will be:

$$a_1a_3a_5|000\rangle+a_1a_3a_6|001\rangle+a_1a_4a_6|011\rangle+a_1a_4a_5|010\rangle+a_2a_4a_6|111\rangle+a_2a_4a_5|110\rangle+a_2a_3a_5|100\rangle+a_2a_3a_6|101\rangle$$

Is this called a **generic product state**?

$$a_1|000\rangle+a_2|001\rangle+a_3|010\rangle+a_4|100\rangle+a_5|110\rangle+a_6|101\rangle+a_7|111\rangle+a_8|011\rangle$$

the second one is called **generic entangled state** am I correct?

Comment: I don't think there is a single really good definition what a generic product or entangled state is.  There is a good definition what a generic state is, though (namely Haar random states).  I would say that being generic (= measure 1) with regard to the restriction of that measure to product/entangled states is good. --  Maybe more generally, if you explore the full parameter space without singularities, you are probably fine.

Comment: ... note that your second state is not generally entangled, so no.

Comment: so if i were to describe these two states in simple terms what would i say? And why isnt the second state generally entangled?@NorbertSchuch

Comment: But the second state is entangled but not generally am I correct?

Comment: what do you mean here with "generic"? Whether by varying the parameters you cover every single product/entangled state? You can write a generic (pure) bipartite entangled state as $\sum_k \sqrt{p_k} |u_k,v_k\rangle$ with $\sum_k p_k=1$ and $p_k\neq0$ for more than one $k$, and for arbitrary orthonormal sets $\{|u_k\rangle\}_k$ and $\{|v_k\rangle\}_k$. I don't know that there is a simple way to write this as an expression of the form you mention though, especially as the multipartite case can get more complicated.